ADF Process XML
I get a response as xml formatted string from some web activity in ADF
    <Transactions>
    <Transaction
    xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\">
    <Header>
        <TransactionType>Type A</TransactionType>
        <BusinessRule>Rule 1</BusinessRule>
    </Header>
    <SimpleRule>
        <RuleCode>Code1223</RuleCode>
        <Description>text</Description>
        <IsDelete>N</IsDelete>
    </SimpleRule>
</Transaction>
<Transaction
    xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\">
    <Header>
        <TransactionType>Type A</TransactionType>
        <BusinessRule>Rule 2</BusinessRule>
    </Header>
    <SimpleRule>
        <RuleCode>CodeXYZ</RuleCode>
        <Description>text ABC</Description>
        <IsDelete>Y</IsDelete>
    </SimpleRule>
</Transaction>
</Transactions>

How can I process it so that I get an array variable with each element being a "Transaction" from that xml?  So, in this case - 2 elements with 2 elements that are properly formatted xml?
I am trying to use @xpath with
@xpath(xml(variables('varTransactionsStr')), '
    //*[name()="Transaction"]
')

but ..
I get the result in some form of encoding that I can't understand
{
    "name": "varTransactions",
    "value": [
        {
            "$content-type": "application/xml;charset=utf-8",
            "$content": "PFRyYW5zYWN0aW9uPg0KICA8SGVhZGVyPg0KICAgIDxUcmFuc2FjdGlvblR5cGU+U0lNUExFUlVMRTwvVHJhbnNhY3Rpb25UeXBlPg0KICAgIDxCdXNpbmVzc1J1bGU+UFJPSkVDVDwvQnVzaW5lc3NSdWxlPg0KICA8L0hlYWRlcj4NCiAgPFNpbXBsZVJ1bGU+DQogICAgPFJ1bGVDb2RlPjQwMTkwMDEwMDAwMDA8L1J1bGVDb2RlPg0KICAgIDxEZXNjcmlwdGlvbj41MzAgQmxkZyBFbGVjdCBGZWVkIFJlcGxhY2U8L0Rlc2NyaXB0aW9uPg0KICAgIDxJc0RlbGV0ZT5OPC9Jc0RlbGV0ZT4NCiAgPC9TaW1wbGVSdWxlPg0KPC9UcmFuc2FjdGlvbj4="
        },
        {
            "$content-type": "application/xml;charset=utf-8",
            "$content": "PFRyYW5zYWN0aW9uPg0KICA8SGVhZGVyPg0KICAgIDxUcmFuc2FjdGlvblR5cGU+U0lNUExFUlVMRTwvVHJhbnNhY3Rpb25UeXBlPg0KICAgIDxCdXNpbmVzc1J1bGU+UFJPSkVDVDwvQnVzaW5lc3NSdWxlPg0KICA8L0hlYWRlcj4NCiAgPFNpbXBsZVJ1bGU+DQogICAgPFJ1bGVDb2RlPjQwMTkwMDIwMDAwMDA8L1J1bGVDb2RlPg0KICAgIDxEZXNjcmlwdGlvbj5aaW1tIFBhbCBWaWxsIExMIFdvcmsgKFBSKSBDQTwvRGVzY3JpcHRpb24+DQogICAgPElzRGVsZXRlPk48L0lzRGVsZXRlPg0KICA8L1NpbXBsZVJ1bGU+DQo8L1RyYW5zYWN0aW9uPg=="
        }
    ]
}

Can anyone help ?  My goal is to get 2 properly formatted xml objects to be send downstream the pipeline. (in a loop)

have you tried string(//*[name()="Transaction"])

Yes, I did.  Tried both.
Actually, the encoded value seems to be a base64 encoded, and if decoded it gives what I need.  What is interesting is that I don't have to use a decoder in the subsequent activities.  It seems that ADF just 'shows' encoded values in the output.  But if used later in a variable or another activity, it is a properly decoded value.    Very unexpected, and strange.

Actually, the encoded value seems to be a base64 encoded, and if decoded it gives what I need.  What is interesting is that I don't have to use a decoder in the subsequent activities.  It seems that ADF just 'shows' encoded values in the output.  But if used later in a variable or another activity, it is a properly decoded value.    Very unexpected, and strange.
